# No Method Error on an unmodified Devise boolean

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I am working on a legacy RoR app and am in the midst of configuring devise (as a replacement for Restful_authentication plugin). I have ran into a very peculiar error. When I try to go to `/users/sign_in` page I get this

```
NoMethodError in Devise::SessionsController#new

undefined method `is_navigational_format?' for #<Devise::SessionsController:0x000000034b2078>
```

The only time I have seen this error referenced is when someone is trying to override the devise session-controller with their own. (https://groups.google.com/d/msg/plataformatec-devise/jyYNhaRztDU/MLsjwxRvf_YJ) I have not tried to do that.

I have installed devise correctly (followed their wiki). I have added `devise_for :users` to my routes. I have restarted the server, many many times. If there is any more info,  or files needed, I will be happy to provide them.

Edit when I ran `$LOAD_PATH.dup` in the rails console the output included

```
"/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/devise-2.2.4/lib", "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/devise-2.2.4/app/controllers", "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/devise-2.2.4/app/helpers", "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/devise-2.2.4/app/mailers"
```

I am using Rails 3.2.13, ruby 1.9.3 and devise 2.2.4
This is the full-stack trace

> devise (2.2.4) app/controllers/devise_controller.rb:119:in `require_no_authentication'
>   activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:418:in`*run*_1218703357271506681__process_action_*3906451143611010656*_callbacks'
>   activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
>   activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in`_run_process_action_callbacks'
>   activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
>   actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in`process_action'
>   actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
>   actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in`block in process_action'
>   activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
>   activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in`instrument'
>   activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
>   actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in`process_action'
>   actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:207:in `process_action'
>   actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in`process'
>   actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
>   actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in`dispatch'
>   actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
>   actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in`block in action'
>   actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
>   actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in`dispatch'
>   actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:36:in `call'
>   actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:42:in`call'
>   journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
>   journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in`each'
>   journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
>   actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:612:in`call'
>   warden (1.2.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
>   warden (1.2.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in`catch'
>   arden (1.2.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
>   actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in`call'
>   rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
>   rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in`call'
>   actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
>   actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in`call'
>   actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
>   rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:210:in`context'
>   rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `call'
>   actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:341:in`call'
>   activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
>   activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:479:in`call'
>   actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
>   activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in`*run*_3871622813520347987_*call*_3063468228496691759__callbacks'
>   activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
>   activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in`_run_call_callbacks'
>   activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
>   actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in`call'
>   actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call'
>   actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in`call'
>   actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
>   actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in`call'
>   railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
>   railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in`block in call'
>   activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
>   railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in`call'
>   actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
>   rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in`call'
>   rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
>   activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in`call'
>   rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
>   actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:63:in`call'
>   railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
>   railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/application.rb:223:in`call'
>   railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
>   passenger (4.0.2) lib/phusion_passenger/rack/thread_handler_extension.rb:77:in`process_request'
>   passenger (4.0.2) lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:135:in `accept_and_process_next_request'
>   passenger (4.0.2) lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:106:in`main_loop'
>   passenger (4.0.2) lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb:449:in `block (4 levels) in start_threads'
>   passenger (4.0.2) lib/phusion_passenger/utils/robust_interruption.rb:108:in`disable_interruptions'
>   passenger (4.0.2) lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb:444:in `block (3 levels) in start_threads'

Comment: Looks like that method is defined in the module `Devise::Controllers::Helpers`: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb#L285. Devise includes these helpers in the ActiveSupport.on_load event for action controller when the Devise railtie is loaded: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/rails.rb#L17. Maybe try some debugging to make sure this is happening? Perhaps you're overriding `Devise::Controllers` or `Devise::Controllers::Helpers`?

Comment: What would be a good way to check to ensure that the on load command is indeed executing? I have not tried to override any devise code, not sure how that would happen by accident.

Comment: You could edit your local Devise install (`bundle show devise` gives you the path) and add a debugger or log statements.